# Expectation Value of The Product of Two Variables

Tags: expected-value

If I wanted to take the expectation value of Z where X and Y are independent say

$Z$ $=$ $XY$ - $\mu_x$$Y$

and $\mu_x$ $=$ $E[x]$ also $\mu_y$ $=$ $E[y]$

I'd first write

$E[Z]$ = $E$$[$$XY$ - $\mu_x$$Y$$]$

Then I'd split them up

$E[Z]$ = $E[XY]$ $-$ $E[$$\mu_x$Y$]$

I think I could treat the $\mu_x$ as a constant but I am not sure how to calculate $E[XY]$?

Comment: Since their independent and have no effect on each other can I just say its the product of the two expectation values but separately? If so is there a specific name for this property?

Comment: Please proof-read your question thoroughly.  As written, it makes little sense.

Comment: @AndrewIgdal Yes since they're independent they're just the product of expectations. This is just a general consequence of independence, but it's related to the fact that independence implies zero covariance.

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Properties (under "**non-multiplicativity**") and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Uncorrelatedness_and_independence ... it's possible to prove that $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$ under independence if you need to.

Comment: [Have a look at some of the many similar posts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=expectation+product++answers%3A1)